# Making a search request in django

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a search bar for my django project but whenever something is searched for it just returns everything which was there by default.

Here is the code from inside views.py:

```
    def index(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, 'Lfm/login.html')
        else:
            lfm = Lfm.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            if query:
                Lfm = lfm.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=query) |
                Q(region__icontains=query) |
                Q(rank__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
                return render(request, 'Lfm/index.html', {'lfm': Lfm,})
            else:
        return render(request, 'Lfm/index.html', {'Lfm': lfm })
```

The models.py file:

```
class Lfm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RANKS)
    rank_sr = models.IntegerField()
    region = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=REGIONS)
    roles = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLES)
    btag = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=14, choices=TIMES)
    logo = models.FileField()
    contact_email = models.EmailField()
```

and the base.html

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'Lfm:index' %}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your filter on your initial query.

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'Lfm/login.html')
    else:
        lfm = Lfm.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user, Q(
            Q(name__icontains=query) |
            Q(region__icontains=query) |
            Q(rank__icontains=query))
            ).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple naming-error!
Your model-class is called `Lfm`. You name your result `Lfm`. That won't work.

Rename your result (e.g. `query_result=lfm.filter(...` and everything should work out.

Btw.: You seem to use many similar, obtrusive names. That creates hard to read code. Try to use more explanatory names and errors like that should happen less often.